# change content dynamically based on dropdown select

Tags: javascript

This is my dropdown menu.

```
<select id="q-rank">
    <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
    <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
    <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
    <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
    <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
</select>
```

The value in the span tags is what I want to change.

```
<span id="q-cd">16</span>
<span id="q-stats1">70</span>
```

This is my javascript.

```
var qSelect = document.getElementById("q-rank");
var qCD = document.getElementById("q-cd");
var qStats1 = document.getElementById("q-stats1");

if(qSelect.value == "1"){
    qCD.innerHTML = "worked";
    qStats1.innerHTML = "70";
}

if(qSelect.value == "2"){
    qCD.innerHTML = "15";
    qStats1.innerHTML = "115";
}

if(qSelect.value == "3"){
    qCD.innerHTML = "14";
    qStats1.innerHTML = "160";
}
```

Initially, when the page loads, the first if statement works. For example, if I change the innerHTML of the first if statement to something like "test", when I load the page, the values in the span tag is "test". However, by selecting "rank 2", it doesn't change the inner HTML of the span tags.

Preferably, I want to accomplish this using pure Javascript but Jquery is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the if statements in a function, and call that function on the change event of the select.

```
<select id="q-rank" onchange="setStats()">
    <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
    <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
    <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
    <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
    <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Really? Accepted with a typo?... Anyway, it would be better to [separate the javascript from the HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content). Use `addEventListener` instead of inline `onchange`.

Comment: It worked so I just accepted as the answer. I will give the event listener a try.

Answer (score 1):

You code works fine, just you need to add `eventListener`, which calls changes every-time when you change `dropdown` value of select, as below.

```js
   var qSelect = document.getElementById("q-rank");
function clck(){
var qCD = document.getElementById("q-cd");
var qStats1 = document.getElementById("q-stats1");

if(qSelect.value == "1"){
qCD.innerHTML = "worked";
qStats1.innerHTML = "70";
}

if(qSelect.value == "2"){
qCD.innerHTML = "15";
qStats1.innerHTML = "115";
}

if(qSelect.value == "3"){
qCD.innerHTML = "14";
qStats1.innerHTML = "160";
}
}
qSelect.addEventListener('change',clck);
```

```html
<select id="q-rank">
    <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
    <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
    <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
    <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
    <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
</select>

<span id="q-cd">16</span>
<span id="q-stats1">70</span>
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener` is not ideal... if the `change` event gets stopped as it bubbles up, `window` will never see it. Use `qSelect.addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use addEventListener  and put your logic inside the function in the javascript.

```
var qSelect = document.getElementById("q-rank");
var qCD = document.getElementById("q-cd");
var qStats1 = document.getElementById("q-stats1");

    qSelect.addEventListener("change", changer, false)
    function changer() {
    if(qSelect.value == "1"){
        qCD.innerHTML = "worked";
        qStats1.innerHTML = "70";
    }

    if(qSelect.value == "2"){
        qCD.innerHTML = "15";
        qStats1.innerHTML = "115";
    }

    if(qSelect.value == "3"){
        qCD.innerHTML = "14";
        qStats1.innerHTML = "160";
    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: It would be better to [separate the javascript from the HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content). Use `addEventListener` instead of inline `onchange`.

Comment: Like :
qSelect.addEventListener("onChange", changer, false);

Comment: `document.getElementById("q-rank").addEventListener("change", changer)`

Comment: This worked only if I put var qCD and var qStats1 inside functioner changer. Is it possible to tie more var to the same addEventListener? Like qSelect, wSelect, eSelect, rSelect.addEventListener?

Comment: You could better put the whole javascript code inside $('document').ready(function(){
      // your code 

}) 

or:

if you want to avoid jQuery try :
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //code to run after DOM is loaded and ready
});

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with some form of a "dictionary":

```js
(function(){
 let qSelect = document.getElementById('q-rank');
 let qCD = document.getElementById('q-cd');
 let qStats1 = document.getElementById('q-stats1');
 
 let values = {
  1: { cd: 'worked', stat: '70' },
  2: { cd: '15', stat: '115' },
  some: { cd: '14', stat: '160' },
  other: { cd: '42', stat: 'hello' },
  key: { cd: 'hey', stat: 'hi' }
 };
 
 qSelect.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let value = values[e.target.value];
  qCD.innerHTML = value.cd;
  qStats1.innerHTML = value.stat;
 });
 
 qSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})();
```

```html
<select id="q-rank">
    <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
    <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
    <option value="some">Rank 3</option>
    <option value="other">Rank 4</option>
    <option value="key">Rank 5</option>
</select>

<span id="q-cd"></span>
<span id="q-stats1"></span>
```